# Send email as Attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sendmail

How can i send my html email content as an attachment of any format.

I am using a FAX API, that allows me to send an attachment with respective Fax Number.
And the API will Fax that Attachment to the Fax Number provided.

here is my code

```
 public string SendFax(int ID)
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        //To address 
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("email@domain.com"));
        message.Subject = "My Subject"; 
        //Specify true if it is html message
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        Class Details = new Class();
        Details = Details.GetDetails(ID);

        string mailBody = File.ReadAllText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Documents/EmailTemplates/FaxTemplate.htm"));

        //Prescriber details.
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("%FirstName%", Details.FirstName);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("%LastName%", Details.LastName);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("%OfficeName%", Details.PracticeName);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("%AddressLIne1%", Details.AddressLine1);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("%Phone%", Details.Phone);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("%FaxNumber%", Details.Fax);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("%DEANumber%", Details.DEANUmber);

        message.Body = mailBody;

        status = Send(message);
        if (status.Equals(string.Empty))
            status = "Failure sending Fax" + "|" + "0";
        else
            status = "Successfully Faxed";
        return status;

    }


 public string Send(MailMessage message)
    {
        string host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPHost"].ToString();
        int port = Convert.ToInt32(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPort"]);
        string username = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPUsername"].ToString();
        string password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPwd"].ToString();
        string fromAddress = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailFrom"].ToString();

        SmtpClient smtpC = new SmtpClient();
        smtpC.Host = host;
        smtpC.Port = port;
        //smtpC.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
        smtpC.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
        smtpC.EnableSsl = false;
        message.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
        smtpC.Send(message);
        status = "Success";
        return status;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text);
        mail.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);
        mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        mail.Body = txtMessage.Text;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        //Attach file using FileUpload Control and put the file in memory stream
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileUpload1.FileName));
        }
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
             ("email@domain.com", "YourGmailPassword");
        //Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);

    }
}
```

If you want to add stream of your data to MailMessage try this

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(ms);
writer.Write("Hello its my sample file");
writer.Flush();
writer.Dispose();

System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, ct);
attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "myFile.txt";

// I guess you know how to send email with an attachment
// after sending email
ms.Close();
```

Comment: there is no attachment existing. I want my message body to go as attachment.

Comment: unfortunately, your answer was not help full. I have to go create a File on my server using the Template.

Comment: what file do you have to create on server? what template?  Please give specifics and I may further assist.

Comment: i have a html template. using that html template i will have to create a pdf file. If you notice in my question. i am using the html template and replacing the content needed. once i replace the content fully. i should save this as a pdf file on the server then i can use this pdf to Fax.

Comment: you don't need to save pdf to server.  Just save it to stream like I showed you above using StreamWriter and write to memory stream.